# Java process dies "Out of swap space" during major GC, with plenty of memory left on machine

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

So I was monitoring a process using VisualVM and I clicked on "Perform GC", the process then died with error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 4088 bytes for char in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_24/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/stack.inline.hpp. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:39), pid=1148, tid=1082808672
#  Error: char in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_24/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/stack.inline.hpp
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /net/bsrs78.pit.twosigma.com/d-1/local/eaMemory2-yao-bsrs78.pit.twosigma.com-db8rsnyc9-head-20110622-130721-31729-0/hs_err_pid1148.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

But not long before I did that, I checked the machine and it seems like there's plenty of memory left (numbers shown in MB):

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96869      60999      35869          0        363       4590
-/+ buffers/cache:      56045      40823
Swap:        10243         40      10203
```

It doesn't seem likely to me that GC will take up all the memory.

This is a problem because if I just let the program continue to run, at some point it will max out its allocated heap and then try to do a major GC and die the same way. Minor GC seems fine though.

So what is going on here? Why does it die with the swap space message? Please let me know if there's anything I can do to provide more information or diagnose this problem further. I will greatly appreciate all help!

Thanks!

Edit1: I've uploaded the error log at http://www.mediafire.com/?kw0meup9mw5de9c, and for what it's worth, it's using PS Scavenge for minor GC and PS MarkSweep for major GC.

Edit2: Also, this problem has happened multiple times, consistently dying in the middle of a major garbage collection -- whether induced by me via visualVM or running out of heap and being triggered by jvm itself.

Comment: Also, what's in that error report file the message mentions?

Comment: Usually out-of-memory would just produce an unchecked exception.  It's quite bad if the VM crashes.  Look at [this](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml) for the minimum amount of memory to run the jvm; on many systems it's 128Mb.

Comment: @bdonlan That's 100G, numbers are displayed in MB. I've uploaded the error log. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, oops, that would make a difference :)

Comment: @welkin, the perm gen seems full; what have you stuck inside try increasing it to `-XX:MaxPermSize=192m`. I have seen quite a bit of JVM crashes but none like  "Out of swap space?", (un)fortunately.

Comment: @bestsss Hmm, out of 4 error logs, 3 indeed are getting close to the max of PermGen. Though in the fourth one, it's only 68% used when it died. Nonetheless I will give this a try, thanks.

Comment: @welkin, btw make sure the hardware is solid, while obvious it's rarely checked.

Comment: The hs_err log file, you uploaded, is incomplete. The 'Dynamic libraries' section is incomplete and 'VM Arguments', 'Environment Variables', 'Signal Handlers' and 'S Y S T E M' sections are missing.

Comment: @Tomas Hurka I only pasted the first part because the "PROCESS" section I wasn't sure if I was allowed to paste since it may contain proprietary information. I'll add the end parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's input. It turns out that our company's system has put a limit (via ulimit) on the amount of virtual memory of the process, which is just ~1G above the amount of heap requested. So the process was denied more memory when it maxed out this limit (apparently major GC will trigger this), even when there was still more virtual memory on the machine (the "out of swap" message is misleading!). Upping the virtual memory limit solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5390563/810918)?  It seems that this is a configuration problem with the VM.

Another example can be found [here](http://www.rune-server.org/runescape-development/rs2-server/help/324028-could-use-help-asap-connecting-hyperion-client-server.html).  The same exact error is reported and fixed by reducing the amount of memory allocated to the virtual machine.

I couldn't download your error log, but I would suggest trying to reduce the memory settings to see if that helps.

Comment: I did look at that question, though "ulimit -d -v" shows it's already set to unlimited.".

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind reducing the amount of heap -- leaving more memory for the underlying JVM compiler etc. But when the machine reports to still have more than 40G of memory left? That makes me think it's a different issue here...

Comment: You could be right, but you could ensure that this isn't the issue by halving your heap size and see if it works (unless your application won't run that way).  The other option is to [tune the garbage collector](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html) or to [enable garbage collection logging](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/GCPortal/) to see what is going on.

Comment: I reran with 25G and it died again. Looking at the gc log, it always dies when a major GC is about to begin. :(

Comment: Is it possible for you to update to the latest version.  From the log, you have update 23 and update 26 is available.  It is possible you have found a bug in the VM.  It looks like update 25 [fixed a lot of bugs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/6u25bugfixes-356453.html), including several garbage collector bugs.  It seems worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that swap space is exhausted and there is a crash due to OOM (OutOfMemoryError) 
This issue has been addressed in JDK-6302804 in 6u25 
Upgrading JVM could avoid this issue.